# Opening email client via Intent (but not to send a message)

Tags: android, android-intent

Is there a way to programically open email client, without a need to forcing message send? I just want the app to let user open his email client for email checking purposes :)

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    intent.setType("message/rfc822");
    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, ""));
```

This code works but it forces user to send a new message.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you should replace `Intent.ACTION_SEND` to `Intent.ACTION_VIEW`,
 i am sure this will work as this will prompt with list of application which support MIME type `"message/rfc822"` so it will include your default email client in your device other than gmail app.

How about this code:

```
final Intent emailLauncher = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
emailLauncher.setType("message/rfc822");
try{
       startActivity(emailLauncher);
}catch(ActivityNotFoundException e){

}
```

Comment: Getting "Can't open this file" on Samsung Galaxy S9, Android 9.0 when running this code. I have a couple of email clients installed.

Comment: Same issue "Can't open this file" in Android 9

Answer (score 40):

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
    intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_APP_EMAIL);
    startActivity(intent);  
    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, getString(R.string.ChoseEmailClient)));
```

That kinda worked. But it opend Gmail for me, even since I have other email clients

Comment: should uses try catch on start activity to avoid exceptions like have no email app.

Comment: Did you ever manage to get the chooser working? It opens gmail for me, and I have another email client installed (myMail).

Comment: You can leave out the last line. Calling `startActivity(intent);` implicitly opens a chooser (unless a default is set), so `createChooser` is not nescessary.

Comment: Or better yet, leave out `startActivity(intent);` and it will open the email chooser for you without picking a default or anything. That works for me.

Comment: I tried this, but it *replaced* my app with the email app, it didn't switch to it

Comment: @ademar111190 this it not necessary, the platform will handle this. I'm seeing "No apps can perform this action" in the picker dialog

Comment: this doesn't catch my Outlook app for some reason but don't let that stop you, Outlook is a sleepy pile of sh$t!

Comment: calling `startActivity` twice seems dodgy to me, are you sure it won't duplicate the handling in some way?

Answer (score 11):

This code will show a dialog with a list of email clients. Clicking one will launch the application:

```
try {
    List<String> emailClientNames = new ArrayList<String>();
    final List<String> emailClientPackageNames = new ArrayList<String>();
    // finding list of email clients that support send email
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO, Uri.fromParts(
        "mailto", "abc@gmail.com", null));
    PackageManager pkgManager = AppController.getContext().getPackageManager();
    List<ResolveInfo> packages = pkgManager.queryIntentActivities(intent, 0);
    if (!packages.isEmpty()) {
        for (ResolveInfo resolveInfo : packages) {
            // finding the package name
            String packageName = resolveInfo.activityInfo.packageName;
            emailClientNames.add(resolveInfo.loadLabel(getPackageManager()).toString());
            emailClientPackageNames.add(packageName);
        }
        // a selection dialog  for the email clients
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MyActivity.this);
        builder.setTitle("Select email client");
        builder.setItems(emailClientNames.toArray(new String[]{}), new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            // on click we launch the right package
            Intent intent = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage(emailClientPackageNames.get(which));
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
        AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
        dialog.show();
    }
} catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
    // Show error message
}
```

Comment: is there a way to display the each applications' icons?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26251260/app-icon-not-visible-in-intent-chooser-in-android this solution includes the app icons alongside

Answer (score 7):

In Kotlin, but this version creates a chooser for user to pick which email app to use.  You basically do what Oved does in his answer, except create an actual chooser using `LabeledIntent`.

```
fun emailAppIntent(): Intent? {
    val emailIntent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("mailto:"))
    val packageManager = appLaunchContext.packageManager

    val activitiesHandlingEmails = packageManager.queryIntentActivities(emailIntent, 0)
    if (activitiesHandlingEmails.isNotEmpty()) {
        // use the first email package to create the chooserIntent
        val firstEmailPackageName = activitiesHandlingEmails.first().activityInfo.packageName
        val firstEmailInboxIntent = packageManager.getLaunchIntentForPackage(firstEmailPackageName)
        val emailAppChooserIntent = Intent.createChooser(firstEmailInboxIntent, "")

        // created UI for other email packages and add them to the chooser
        val emailInboxIntents = mutableListOf<LabeledIntent>()
        for (i in 1 until activitiesHandlingEmails.size) {
            val activityHandlingEmail = activitiesHandlingEmails[i]
            val packageName = activityHandlingEmail.activityInfo.packageName
            val intent = packageManager.getLaunchIntentForPackage(packageName)
            emailInboxIntents.add(
                LabeledIntent(
                    intent,
                    packageName,
                    activityHandlingEmail.loadLabel(packageManager),
                    activityHandlingEmail.icon
                )
            )
        }
        val extraEmailInboxIntents = emailInboxIntents.toTypedArray()
        return emailAppChooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS, extraEmailInboxIntents)
    } else {
        return null
    }
}
```

.. then later call it with

```
val emailChooserIntent = emailAppIntent()

if (emailChooserIntent != null) {
    startActivity(emailAppIntent())
}
```

or handle null however you want.

Comment: Thanks, this was the only solution that did open the app chooser. all others just started Gmail

Answer (score 0):

A bit more modern solution in Kotlin

```
    fun tryVerifyMail() {
        try {
            val intents: List<Intent> = (packageManager.queryIntentActivities(Intent(
                Intent.ACTION_SENDTO, Uri.fromParts(
                    "mailto", "lowhillgamesoy@gmail.com", null
                )
            ), 0) + packageManager.queryIntentActivities(Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW).also {
                it.type = "message/rfc822"
            }, 0)).mapNotNull {
                it.activityInfo.packageName
            }.toSet().mapNotNull {
                packageManager.getLaunchIntentForPackage(it)
            }

            if(intents.size > 0) {
                startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intents.first(), getString(R.string.verify_mail)).also {
                    if(intents.size > 1) {
                        it.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS, intents.subList(1, intents.size - 1).toTypedArray())
                    }
                }, OPEN_MAIL_REQUEST_CODE)
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Verify your e-mail by clicking the link in your e-mail inbox.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
            }


        } catch (e: ActivityNotFoundException) {
            // Show error message
            e.printStackTrace()
        }
    }
```

This also picks both mail clients only supporting ACTION_SEND and ACTION_VIEW and removes duplicates.