# App icon not visible in intent chooser in Android

Tags: android, android-intent

i am opening an intent chooser to send a url

```
Intent sendIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Text to send");
sendIntent.setType("text/plain");
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sendIntent, "Complete Action using.."));
```

The issue is that the images for the apps are not visible. Please see the screenshot attached.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

There are lot of questions asked on stackoverflow regarding this issue. The code i am using for showing list with icons in intentChooser is below -

```
public void onShareClick(View v) {
        Resources resources = getResources();

        Intent emailIntent = new Intent();
        emailIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        // Native email client doesn't currently support HTML, but it doesn't hurt to try in case they fix it
        emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, Html.fromHtml(resources.getString(R.string.share_email_native)));
        emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, resources.getString(R.string.share_email_subject));
        emailIntent.setType("message/rfc822");

        PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
        Intent sendIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);     
        sendIntent.setType("text/plain");


        Intent openInChooser = Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, resources.getString(R.string.share_chooser_text));

        List<ResolveInfo> resInfo = pm.queryIntentActivities(sendIntent, 0);
        List<LabeledIntent> intentList = new ArrayList<LabeledIntent>();        
        for (int i = 0; i < resInfo.size(); i++) {
            // Extract the label, append it, and repackage it in a LabeledIntent
            ResolveInfo ri = resInfo.get(i);
            String packageName = ri.activityInfo.packageName;
            if(packageName.contains("android.email")) {
                emailIntent.setPackage(packageName);
            } else if(packageName.contains("twitter") || packageName.contains("facebook") || packageName.contains("mms") || packageName.contains("android.gm")) {
                Intent intent = new Intent();
                intent.setComponent(new ComponentName(packageName, ri.activityInfo.name));
                intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                intent.setType("text/plain");
                if(packageName.contains("twitter")) {
                    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, resources.getString(R.string.share_twitter));
                } else if(packageName.contains("facebook")) {
                    // Warning: Facebook IGNORES our text. They say "These fields are intended for users to express themselves. Pre-filling these fields erodes the authenticity of the user voice."
                    // One workaround is to use the Facebook SDK to post, but that doesn't allow the user to choose how they want to share. We can also make a custom landing page, and the link
                    // will show the <meta content ="..."> text from that page with our link in Facebook.
                    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, resources.getString(R.string.share_facebook));
                } else if(packageName.contains("mms")) {
                    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, resources.getString(R.string.share_sms));
                } else if(packageName.contains("android.gm")) {
                    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, Html.fromHtml(resources.getString(R.string.share_email_gmail)));
                    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, resources.getString(R.string.share_email_subject));               
                    intent.setType("message/rfc822");
                }

                intentList.add(new LabeledIntent(intent, packageName, ri.loadLabel(pm), ri.icon));
            }
        }

        // convert intentList to array
        LabeledIntent[] extraIntents = intentList.toArray( new LabeledIntent[ intentList.size() ]);

        openInChooser.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS, extraIntents);
        startActivity(openInChooser);       
    }
```

Hope this helps you.

Comment: Kindly post the many questions link already asked here so that i can look at those too.

Answer (score 1):

I think that Ashish is not actually answering the question....

In fact, I had suffered from this problem for a long time before, when I have finally found the cause.

The culprit is the AsyncTask running in background, while launching chooser.  I think that the intent chooser is also using AsyncTask to load icons.  However, Android allows the app to run only one AsyncTask running at one moment, and the task loading the icon is given up.

After I moved my AsyncTask job to Thread, those icons came back.

Comment: Your starting hypothesis, that Android doesn't allow more than a single AsyncTask to run at the same time, isn't actually true (I have both documentation and a running app with more than a single AsyncTask running proving it).

Comment: Yes, you are right. I overlooked. Using executeOnExecutor() can make AsyncTask running in parallel.