# Open email client for reading

Tags: android

I am trying to display a native chooser for the email client and navigate the user to his email application after registration. I have only found a solution to send new emails, not for reading them.

I found possible solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13848423/opening-email-client-via-intent-but-not-to-send-a-message) but it always opens Gmail app.

Comment: Did the user once check "always use this app" for GMail?

Comment: What has registration to do with that what you want?